# The plugin jetpack/jetpack.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist

Tags: plugin-jetpack

When try to install the latest JetPack plugin, I got below error:

The plugin jetpack/jetpack.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.

Tried many times to install but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consideration, I decided to take backup of **wp-content/plugins/jetpack** and then delete **jetpack** folder, after that I installed the latest version with out any problem. I hope this will help you.

[For more information please check](http://scientistz.com/forums/topic/solved-the-plugin-jetpack-jetpack-php-has-been-deactivated-due-to-an-error-plugin-file-does-not-exist/)

Answer (score 0):

go to database in myphp section fine line in

[pluginsjetpack delete it reinstall jetpack](https://androidtechpro.com/the-plugin-jetpack-jetpack-php-has-been-deactivated-due-to-an-error-plugin-file-does-not-exist/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).